# sp_add_jobstep in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written this in SQL:

```
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Every 5 minutes log backup ',
    @step_name = N'set T-sql command',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command=N'DECLARE @fileName NVARCHAR(256) BACKUP LOG MM TO DISK =''F:\BackUp\Log\M-''' +dbo.UDF_Gregorian_To_Persian_WithDash(cast(GETDATE() as date))+'''-'''+ REPLACE(cast(isnull(convert(char(5), GETDATE(), 108),'''''')  as nvarchar),''':''','''''') + '''.TRN''',
    @retry_attempts = 1,
    @retry_interval = 1 ;
GO
```

but SQL says

> "Incorrect syntaxt near +" !

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass *variables* into [`EXEC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188332.aspx) or literal *values* but what you're not allowed to use are *expressions*.

So do your string concatenation as a separate step first:

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @cmd = 'DECLARE @fileName NVARCHAR(256) BACKUP ... ' + dbo.UDF_Gregorian_To_Persian_WithDash(...) + ' ... '
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Every 5 minutes log backup ',
    @step_name = N'set T-sql command',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command=@cmd,
    @retry_attempts = 1,
    @retry_interval = 1 ;
```

Comment: If I pass @cmd the date and time are not uptodate, because I need to have the exact date and Time for naming the log backup file

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a mess with those apostophes. What you want is:

```
DISK ='F:\BackUp\Log\M-x-y.TRN'
```

But by looking at the current string it would rather be:

```
DISK ='F:\BackUp\Log\M-'x'-'y'.'TRN'
```

So, I hope this will work better:

```
@command = N'DECLARE @fileName NVARCHAR(256) BACKUP LOG MM TO DISK = ''F:\BackUp\Log\M-' + cast(dbo.UDF_Gregorian_To_Persian_WithDash(cast(GETDATE() as date)) as nvarchar) + '-' + REPLACE(cast(isnull(convert(char(5), GETDATE(), 108),'''''')  as nvarchar),''':''','''''') + '.TRN'''
```

A tip would be to *print* this line so you can see exactly how the output will be. In my example above the output will be something like:

```
..DISK ='F:\BackUp\Log\M-2015-04-27-08:31.TRN'
```

**Edit:**

Not sure what `UDF_Gregorian_To_Persian_WithDash` returns, but unless it is a `nvarchar` you'll need to `CAST()` that too (updated my example above with the cast).

Comment: @user2315036 You can see an example of it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9e1a5/2 (Run SQL). The query is returning the expected result anyway. Do you have any new error messages?

Comment: As Damien mentioned the exec won't accept expressions (doh). Not sure how to get this in to the job and then parsed in there.